# 2 jQuery datepickers 1 input field

Tags: jquery

I would like to display 2 datepicker calendars (no restrictions) from 1 input field, how may I achieve this?

```
 $(function() {
    var date1 = $('#date1');
    var date2 = $('#date2');
    date1.datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");

            date2.datepicker("setDate", date);
            date2.datepicker( "show" );

        }
    });
    date2.datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
            var formattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);

            date1.val(date1.val() + " - " + formattedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v2m4pn0h/ for a sketch draft of what I need - but only 1 calendar shows and the code is also unstable (try clicking the input field and clicking on the document multiple times and see what happens).

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: I totally misunderstood you, I thought the problem was the placement of the second calendar popup (that appears to the right). So how about using a [daterangepicker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples) rather than using the JQuery UI datepicker?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to work with two invisible inputs and one display container to show the selected date range. The two hidden elements are placed behind the display container as this makes sure the datepicker calendars are shown in the right spot.

```js
$(function() {
   var date1 = $('#date1');
   var date2 = $('#date2');
   var completeDate = $('#complete_date');

   date1.datepicker({
     defaultDate: "+1w",
     changeMonth: true,
     numberOfMonths: 1,
     onClose: function(selectedDate) {
       var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
       var formattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
       completeDate.val(formattedDate);
       date2.datepicker("setDate", date);
       date2.datepicker("show");


     }
   });
   date2.datepicker({
     defaultDate: "+1w",
     changeMonth: true,
     numberOfMonths: 1,
     onClose: function(selectedDate) {
       var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
       var formattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
       completeDate.val(completeDate.val() + ' - ' + formattedDate);
     }
   });

   $('#complete_date').on('click', function() {
     date1.datepicker("show");
   })
 });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.date_wrapper {
  position: relative;  
}

.display_element {
  min-width: 150px;
}

.invisible {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="date_wrapper">
  <input type="text" class="display_element" id="complete_date" value="" placeholder="(Choose date range)" />
  <input id="date1" class="invisible" value="" />
  <input id="date2" class="invisible" value="" />
</div>
```